# Prevent multiple recipients of group message to be displayed on other recipients

Tags: sms, privacy, contact-groups

I once sent a message to multiple recipients and my friend told me he could see the other recipients and that it was a group message. This was a while ago and he was using a BlackBerry (though my phone was Android).

How does this work and can you make it so that if a message has multiple recipients, they appear to each one as if they're the only recipient?

Comment: You mean like a [BCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy) field in an e-mail message?

Comment: yea...so when you add multiple recipients it appears as a cc?